# why am i getting an error on .verifyCredentials()

Tags: java, android, twitter

I want to get the data using twitter's fabric api but whenever i tend to verify credentials and use a callback it shows an error , specifically ,"The arguments differ in length"

```
void getUserData() {
        Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

                        User user = userResult.data;
                        String twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;

                        try {
                            Log.d("imageurl", user.profileImageUrl);
                            Log.d("name", user.name);
                            Log.d("email",user.email);
                            Log.d("des", user.description);
                            Log.d("followers ", String.valueOf(user.followersCount));
                            Log.d("createdAt", user.createdAt);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                });


    }
```

Comment: error,class or enum unexpected

Comment: It is a compile time error actually

Answer (score 2):

If you check the fabric documentation, it shows two version of the method, however when I tried to open the source code in Android Studio but it had only the version without the callback.

You can solve the isssue as follows:

```
//Getting the account service of the user logged in
Call<User> call = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
        .verifyCredentials(true, false);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            //If any error occurs handle it here
        }
        @Override
        public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
            //If it succeeds creating a User object from userResult.data
            User user = userResult.data;
                    String twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;

                    try {
                        Log.d("imageurl", user.profileImageUrl);
                        Log.d("name", user.name);
                        Log.d("email",user.email);
                        Log.d("des", user.description);
                        Log.d("followers ", String.valueOf(user.followersCount));
                        Log.d("createdAt", user.createdAt);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    });
```

[Source](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/twitter-login-android-tutorial-using-fabric-twitter-login-kit/)

[Documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twitter-core/1.4.0/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/services/AccountService.html)

Comment: Say, now that the SDK has changed, it has an additional parameter of `verifyCredentials`, named "includeEmail". Should I set it to true or false? What does it even do? How did it work before? With true, or false?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the twitter dependency in  your Build.Gradle 
from

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

to

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.11.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

The new version of the .verifyCredentials() method doesn't accept a callback hence your error.

Comment: You don't need to set transitive to true if you remove the `@aar` from your dependency.